# If you roll two fair six-sided dice, what is the probability that the sum is 4 or higher?

Tags: probability, dice

> If you roll two fair six-sided dice, what is the probability that the sum is $4$ or higher?

The answer is $\frac{33}{36}$ or $\frac{11}{12}$. I understand how to arrive at this answer. What I don't understand is why the answer isn't $\frac{9}{11}$? When summing the results after rolling two fair six sided dice, there are $11$ equally possible outcomes: $2$ through $12$. Two of these outcomes are below four, meaning $9$ are greater than or equal to four which is how I arrived at $\frac{9}{11}$. Can someone help explain why that is wrong?

Comment: There are two outcomes when you play the lottery.  You either win or you lose.  The probability of winning however is usually not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Off topic: actually the problem is ill-posed, because it can happen that each of the two dice is fair but their outcomes aren't independent. In the most extreme case where the two dice always have the same outcome, the answer would be $5/6$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: That was one my father's jokes. "What's the probability that an elephant sits in front of our porch?". "Either there's an elephant, or there isn't one. The probability must be 50% then!"

Comment: @user1551 The problem is not ill-posed, calling a die fair implies that the outcomes of different rolls are independent.

Comment: @JiK No, in the question you don't roll a die *twice*. You roll *two* dice. A fair die means a die whose outcomes from different throws are independent and equally probable. That doesn't indicate how the outcomes from multiple dice are correlated, although In normal context, we do implicitly assume that the outcomes from different fair dice are independent.

Comment: @user1551 One is going to have a lot of trouble interpreting probability questions by thinking that a fair die roll is allowed to depend on external events.

Comment: Great, now I'm trying to figure out how to map quantum entanglement to fair dice

Comment: @Foon clearly the dice either roll fairly or they don't, but you won't know until the cat knocks them off the table.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is wrong because it is not $11$ equally possible outcome.

There is exactly $1$ way to get the sum to be $2$. ($1+1=2$)

but there is more than one way to get $3$. ($1+2=3, 2+1=3$)

Comment: To add to this, there are 36 equally possible outcomes. 6 on one die and 6 on the other, 6 x 6 = 36. 1 of those outcomes is a 2, 2 of those outcomes is a 3 so (36 - 3)/36 outcomes 4 or higher.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out by others, the possible sums of the dice don't all have an equal probability of showing up. To see this, you can write it all out:

```
Die 1 | Die 2 | result
  1       1       2
  1       2       3
  1       3       4
  ...
  6       5      11
  6       6      12
```

When you  look at the resulting table, there are 36 combinations. 1 of those is a 2 (ie you have a 1 in 36 chance of getting a 2 from D1 + D2), 2 of those are '3' etc.

Now it's easy to see how to get the chance of getting a 4 or higher.

Comment: I like this because it's trivial to do, but it makes everything suddenly obvious.

Answer (score 9):

$\frac9{11}$ is wrong precisely because it assumes the probabilities of getting each sum are equal. Here they are not: there's only one way to roll a sum of two (the snake eyes of gambling jargon) but six ways to roll a seven.

Answer (score 4):

if the correct answer is $ \frac {33}{36}$ it means there are 36 possible results.. You should try to write them down..It will be more clear. You just used equiprobability in a case where there isn't equiprobability..$P(1)=0 \quad P(2) =1/36,\quad P(3)=2/36 ,\quad P(4)=3/36,$

$ P(5)=4/36 \quad P(6)=5/36 \quad P(7)=6/36 \quad P(8)=5/36 \quad  $

$ P(9)=4/36 \quad P(10)=3/36 \quad P(11)=2/36 \quad P(12)=1/36$

And the answer is just:
$$P=1-P(1)-P(2)-P(3)=\frac {33}{36}$$

Comment: Nitpick:  if the answer is  $\frac{x}{36}$ then there are *at least* 36 possible results, but if you don't know it's dice, there could b $36*n$possibilities, with  $x*n$ desired outcomes

Comment: "If the correct answer is $\frac{33}{36}$ it means there are 36 possible results." Definitely not. For one: I can build a weighted coin that comes up heads 33 times out of 36, despite there being only two possible outcomes. For another: $\frac{33}{36}=\frac{3300}{3600}$ and it would be silly to claim that this therefore means there are 3600 possible results.

Comment: yes @DanielWagner  you are right

Answer (score 4):

Your probabilities are wrong. For each value of die 1, there are 6 possible values of die 2, the available scores for a roll of two dice are: (7 is the most likely score)

```
2,3,4,5,6,7

  3,4,5,6,7,8

    4,5,6,7,8,9

      5,6,7,8,9,10

        6,7,8,9,10,11

          7,8,9,10,11,12
```

So, out of the 36 total possible outcomes, 33 of them have a value of 4 or higher, or 33:36, or 11:12